# Finding the value of y for given equation?

Tags: logic

Given the equation :
*x* *&* *y* = *x*, where *x*, *y* are positive integers.

Note: Here '*&*' stands for Bitwise operator AND between two numbers.

I am provided with the value of *x*. Can I find possible values of *y* satisfying the given equation ?

Thanks for help!

Comment: We need to conserve all the "1" bits of $x$ and no other "1" bits. Looking at [the truth table of AND](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/B261/truth_tables.html), we can observe that $y$ needs to have a value of "1" in all positions in which $x$ also has values of "1". The rest do not matter, as the "0"s of $x$ will cancel them out anyway.

Comment: @potestasity Make an answer?